# How to get WebKit cookies with C?

Tags: c, webkit, gtk

This is what I have right now:

```
#include <webkit2/webkit2.h>

WebKitWebContext *ctx = webkit_web_context_get_default ();
WebKitCookieManager * mgr = webkit_web_context_get_cookie_manager ( ctx); 

webkit_cookie_manager_get_domains_with_cookies(mgr,0,0,0);
webkit_cookie_manager_get_cookies(mgr, "https://google.com", 0,0,0);
```

Surprisingly it doesn't compile:

```
undefined reference to `webkit_cookie_manager_get_cookies'
```

Although `webkit_cookie_manager_get_domains_with_cookies` is fine. Both of these functions are listed in the docs:

https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/unstable/WebKitCookieManager.html

I'm on Ubuntu with `libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2` installed.

Thanks

Comment: You link is documentation for unstable release. The function in question is available since 2.20. According to [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2) your version is 2.18, no surprise this function is not available. I recommend you to install documentation and browse it via `devhelp`

Comment: Thanks, @AlexanderDmitriev! I wonder how cookies were fetched before 2.20.

Comment: I haven't worked with webkitgtk, but looks like `webkit_website_data_manager_fetch` is what you need. It returns `WebKitWebsiteData`, which can be of `WEBKIT_WEBSITE_DATA_COOKIES` type

Comment: Thanks. Can you post this as an answer, so I can accept it? I'm surprised such essential functionality was implemented  only in late 2017.

Comment: I won't post it as an answer unless you check it out and confirm it works.